# Is it possible to keep running nunit scripts even if error occurs

Tags: c#, loops, nunit

I have a test which reads input from csv file and executes all test based on input in a loop and also write back results in same file for each row executed. Problem is it is failing to run the whole input data even if error occurs in single input data. Is it possible to keep running the tests even if one of the input data failed.

Please guide.
Thanks

Code

```
[Test, Category(TestConstants.DataCategoryName)]
    public void GenerateTestData_Book()
    {
    string csv_file_path = GetAppSettingsEntry("CSVResourcesPath", true);
    DataTable csvData = GetDataFromCSVFile(csv_file_path);

        for (int i = 0; i < csvData.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            var request = TestData.Helper.GetBooks<RequestedBook>(csvData.Rows[i][0]);


            string errors = string.Empty;
            if (response.HasErrors())
            {
                errors = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, response.ResponseInfos.GetErrors().Select(x => x.Code + " " + x.Text));
                UpdateColumnInCSVFile(csv_file_path,error, errors, Convert.ToString(csvData.Rows[i][0]));
            }
            else
            {
                // Save Book id in file
                UpdateColumnInCSVFile(csv_file_path, Reference, Convert.ToString(response.Book.Bookid), Convert.ToString(csvData.Rows[i][0]));
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Please, show code which you use to run tests

Comment: Sounds like a case for [`TestCaseSourceAttribute`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.6.3) to test your input files separately.

Answer (score 0):

You should just put a try-catch inside your for loop. 
If you want the test to fail on error you could store a bool declared before the loop and make a assert.isTrue after the loop.

Something like this:

```
 public void GenerateTestData_Book()
    {
    string csv_file_path = GetAppSettingsEntry("CSVResourcesPath", true);
    DataTable csvData = GetDataFromCSVFile(csv_file_path);

    bool hasError = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < csvData.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            //do your stuff here....
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            hasError = true;
        }
    }

    Assert.IsFalse(hasError);
}
```